# Is the Pythagorean theorem one of the assumptions needed in order to make special relativity consistent?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor

In all the formulations of special relativity I have seen and I am no expert mind you and in fact a beginner I have noticed that the Pythagorean theorem is always used in one form or fashion to complete the arguments of clocks slowing and rulers shrinking. Is it necessary? That is ( If S.R. is true => Pythagorean theorem must be true. ) Obviously the reverse is not true. The second part of the question I could not fit in the box and may need  a separate posting but it requires someone familiar with special and general relativity.  First of all is it true that Pythagorean theorem only holds in cases of right triangles so can we assume it cannot be used in general relativity? And now for the motivation to the question.  If general relativity requires space time to bend wouldn't that violate the 90 degree requirement for the Pythagorean theorem and would it then not be the case that the truth of both special and general relativity would be logically inconsistent? Obviously that cannot be the case since they are one of the most well tested theories of mankind so I need help to find the mistakes in my reasoning.

Comment: Says "edited"  but I don't see that my question was edited.  In any event does not matter the answer below was accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Pythagoras applications in special relativity are usually introduced to students over finite scales instead of infinitesimal ones. But these applications boil down to certain expressions for scalars obtained by contracting infinitesimal vectors, such as the fact that the theory's invariant line element is $$ds^2=\eta_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu=c^2 dt^2-\sum_i dx_i^2=c^2dt^2\left( 1-\sum_i \beta_i^2\right)=\left(\dfrac{cdt}{\gamma}\right)^2$$in Cartesian coordinates. Essentially the use of Pythagoras is on the nondimensionalised, unphysical Euclidean space containing the vector $\boldsymbol{\beta}$.

In general relativity the role of $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ is replaced with a more general metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$, viz. $ds^2=g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu$. The spacetime manifold is still Riemannian, which means that an infinitesimal patch of it still admits a local coordinate system that looks like that of special relativity. The *infinitesimal* version of Pythagoras therefore still works in these coordinates, so there is no risk of non-Euclidean angle behaviour breaking the proofs of infinitesimal results.

Comment: I  accept your response  although I must admit I must do a little research on your equations.  Ultimately these equations should be reflective of reality so I am amazed that near the earth's surface ...like me sitting at my desk and measuring a right triangle the effect of the earth bending space would not be more obvious.  I can only imagine the bend is ever so slight?.

Comment: @Sedumjoy In short, the bend is slight when your distance from Earth's centre is much greater than its Schwarzschild radius (because it's proportional to the ratio of these distances), which is true because Earth's radius is about 6400 km while its Schwarzschild radius is 9 mm. This is similar to the fact that speeds much less than $c$ make time dilation etc negligible.